# google will no longer allow OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers known as “web-views

Tags: google-oauth

google said they will no longer allow OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers known as “web-views. actually starting 20 April 2017.

I work for LGE. 
LG has been using android and ios webView in many services.

Changing it to android and ios sdk makes so many trouble in our company.

Dose anyone knows about this solution?

Is there any way to use webview countinuingly?

And..

Google said they will start blocking OAuth requests using web-views for all OAuth clients on platforms where viable alternatives exist.

LG smart TV uses WebOs platform, so there is no alternatives exists except for
using webviews.

how can we request exception for webos platforms?